# stripping the first part of piped output

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script that outputs the following:

```
SUM = 137892134.0000000
```

I need to strip off the first part of the string, leaving only the number, formatted as an integer if possible.  I'm assuming I need to use `sed` but I seem to have zero capacity to learn it.

I need to be able to write a conditional statement that can operate if the value is less than 100.  I don't know if I can do this in a bash script, but that will be the second part of my challenge.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your original bash script so that it just returns what you want?

Comment: No. I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form of a substitution with sed is:

```
s/replace this/with this/
```

Where "replace this" and "with this" are both regular expressions.  In your case, you want to completely get rid of the literal string "SUM = " at the beginning and the decimal at the end. So:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=$(your_script.sh | sed 's/^SUM = //' | sed 's/\..*//')
if ! egrep -q '^[0-9]+$' <<< $sum; then
    echo "your_script.sh printed unexpected output!"
    exit 1
fi
if [ $sum -lt 100 ]; then
    echo "$sum is less than 100"
else
    echo "$sum is not less than 100"
fi
```

The first line is what turns "SUM = 137892134.0000000" into "137892134".  The first sed replaces "SUM = " at the beginning of the string (`^`) with nothing (i.e., deletes it).  The second sed finds the first period character (`\.`) and replaces it and everything after it (`.*`) with nothing.  The resulting string is then saved to the variable `$sum` using `$(...)`.

The if-statement that uses egrep is checking to make sure that the value we saved in `$sum` is actually an integer, and bails if it's not.

The second if-statement compares the value of $sum, which we now know is an integer, with 100.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how you want to handle "123.789" (whether you would print 124 or 123 when printing as an integer).  Consider:

```
if $( echo SUM = 137892134.0000000 | awk '{printf "%d", $3}' ) -lt 100; then
   echo the value is less than 100!!
fi
```

You can also do:

```
if echo SUM = 137892134.0000000 | awk '$3 >= 100 { exit 1}'; then
    echo the value is less than 100!!
fi
```

or

```
if ! echo SUM = 137892134.0000000 | awk '{exit $3 < 100}'; then
     echo the value is less than 100!!
fi
```

Note that the logic is a little convoluted as `awk` returning 1 evaluates to failure, so the comparison operator is the inverse of what might be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use `sed` to do this:

```
echo 'SUM = 137892134.0000000' | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g' | sed 's/\..*//g'
```

This is what the output should look like: `137892134`.

**Some explanation on the commands:**

- `sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'` tells `sed` to remove any characters that are not numbers (`0`-`9`) or periods (`.`)
- `sed 's/\..*//g'` tells `sed` to remove any characters (`.*`) after a decimal (`\.`)
- Also, instead of using `echo`, you can use the output from your original script for that first part... and then it can be piped into `sed` to eventually get the final "int" that you want.

*Note: this does not take into account any **rounding issues** as brought up by William Pursell.*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
bashScript | sed 's/.* \(.*\)\.0*/\1/'
```

In English: "Take a bunch of stuff followed by a space, followed by *something*, followed by a dot and maybe some zeroes, and replace all of that with the *something*."